# How Can I use swiper zoom on next js Image?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, swiper.js, react-swiper

I'm using react-swiper with next js creating an album.

When I write the below code it works fine with img tag:

```
 <Swiper
            style={
              {
                '--swiper-navigation-color': '#fff',
                '--swiper-pagination-color': '#fff',
              } as any
            }
            pagination={{
              type: 'fraction',
              horizontalClass:
                'bg-[#f1f1f180] py-1 w-14 rounded-md opacity-0 z-10 group-hover:opacity-100',
            }}
            zoom
            navigation
            keyboard
            spaceBetween={15}
            onSwiper={swiper => {ref.current = swiper}}
            thumbs={{
              swiper:
                thumbsSwiper && !thumbsSwiper.destroyed ? thumbsSwiper : null,
            }}
            dir="rtl"
            modules={[FreeMode, Navigation, Thumbs, Zoom, Pagination, Keyboard]}
            className="ModalSwiper relative ImageModalGallery group">
            {images &&
              images.map((image: string, index: number) => (
                <SwiperSlide key={index}>
                  <div className="md:w-[500px] h-[350px] md:h-[450px] swiper-zoom-container relative">
                    <img
                      src={`${BASEURL}/Api/Files/${image}`}
                      className="rounded"
                    />
                  </div>
                </SwiperSlide>
              ))}

        {/* zoom in and zoom out icons */}
        <div className="flex justify-center absolute bottom-0 w-full mx-auto text-white z-50">
          <button
            className=""
            style={{ width: '30px' }}
            onClick={() => {ref.current.zoom.in()}}>
            <svg
              className="App-buttonIcon"
              viewBox="0 0 24 24"
              fill="white">
              <path d="M12 ... 0-2z" />
            </svg>
          </button>
          <button className="" style={{ width: '30px' }}>
            <svg
              className=""
              viewBox="0 0 24 24"
              fill="white"
              onClick={() => {ref.current.zoom.in()}}>
              <path d="M12 ... 0-2z" />
            </svg>
          </button>
        </div>
      </Swiper>
```

In the same code when I replace img tag with Next js Image tag I can not zoom in and out of image :

```
  <SwiperSlide key={index}>
      <div className="md:w-[500px] h-[350px] md:h-[450px] swiper-zoom-container relative">
        <Image
          src={`${BASEURL}/Api/Files/${image}`}
          className="rounded"
          objectFit="contain"
          layout="fill"
        />
      </div>
    </SwiperSlide>
```

thanks in advance for any suggestions and answers!

[image for better understanding situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26tEC.png)